# Scenario where i can use only redirect not forward or it would be better to use than forward?

Tags: web-applications, servlets

In every webapplication i have used forward. i want to know the scenario where i can use only redirect not forward or where redirect will be advantageous to use if compare to forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example: a web gallery. The client upload pictures then set some metadata on the `/createGallery` url and click the OK button which calls a servlet. The servlet create a new record in the database with the given metadata and generate a random key. Then it redirects the browser to the `/gallery.jsp?secretKey=<randomkey>` url. After that the user could copy the url from the address bar of the browser and could send his friends or share on Twitter, Facebook etc. or just save as a bookmark. If you use forward the url in the address bar remains `/createGallery` and the friends will not see the cute pictures. The service also could be a custom RSS channel, a calendar (Doodle also use this kind of redirects), a web forum, etc.

Of course a "workaround" is using forward and put the `/gallery.jsp?secretKey=<randomkey>` link to the generated page but it's ugly a little bit and has all the disadvantages which @BalusC mentioned.